# A bit lost with preg_match regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm a beginner in regular expression so it didn't take long for me to get totally lost :]

What I need to do:

I've got a string of values 'a:b,a2:b2,a3:b3,a4:b4' where I need to search for a specific pair of values (ie: a2:b2) by the second value of the pair given (b2) and get the first value of the pair as an output (a2).

All characters are allowed (except ',' which seperates each pair of values) and any of the second values (b,b2,b3,b4) is unique (cant be present more than once in the string)

Let me show a better example as the previous may not be clear:

This is a string: 2 minutes:2,5 minutes:5,10 minutes:10,15 minutes:15,never:0

Searched pattern is: 5

I thought, the best way was to use function called preg_match with subpattern feature.

So I tried the following:

```
$str = '2 minutes:2,5 minutes:5,10 minutes:10,15 minutes:15,20 minutes:20,30 minutes:30, never:0';

$re = '/(?P<name>\w+):5$/';
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);

echo $matches['name'];
```

Wanted output was '5 minutes' but it didn't work.

I would also like to stick with Perl-Compatible reg. expressions as the code above is included in a PHP script.

Can anyone help me out? I'm getting a little bit desperate now, as Ive spent on this most of the day by now ...

Thanks to all of you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = '2 minutes:2,51 seconds:51,5 minutes:5,10 minutes:10,15 minutes:51,never:0';
$search = 5;

preg_match("~([^,\:]+?)\:".preg_quote($search)."(?:,|$)~", $str, $m);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($m); echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5 minutes:5
    [1] => 5 minutes
)
```

Comment: `$search` would have, in general, to be escaped (see `preg_quote`); plus your expression would fail if there was another pair were the second element started with 5 that appeared before the pair `5 minutes:5`. -1

Comment: 2Artefacto: unfortunately true. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Well reasonable notes. Updated. Seems like it fixes mentioned issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
$re = '/(?:^|,)(?P<name>[^:]*):5(?:,|$)/';
```

Besides the problem of your expression having to match `$` after 5, which would only work if 5 were the last element, you also want to make sure that after `5` either nothing comes or another pair comes; that before the first element of the pair comes either another element or the beginning of the string, and you want to match more than `\w` in the first element of the pair.

Answer (score 0):

A `preg_match` call will be shorter for certain, but I think I wouldn't bother with regular expressions, and instead just use string and array manipulations.

```
$pairstring = '2 minutes:2,5 minutes:5,10 minutes:10,15 minutes:15,20 minutes:20,30 minutes:30, never:0';

function match_pair($searchval, $pairstring) {
  $pairs = explode(",", $str);
  foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
    $each = explode(":", $pair);
    if ($each[1] == $searchval) {
      echo $each[0];
    }
  }
}

// Call as:
match_pair(5, $pairstring);
```

Comment: This was my very first working solution (using string function + foreach), but I thought that preg_match would be a bit faster and shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same as `@Michael`'s. It doesn't search for an element but constructs an array of the string. You say that values are unique so they are used as keys in my array:

```
$str = '2 minutes:2,5 minutes:5,10 minutes:10,15 minutes:15,20 minutes:20,30 minutes:30, never:0';
$a = array();
foreach(explode(',', $str) as $elem){
    list($key, $val) = explode(':', $elem);
    $a[$val] = $key;
}
```

Then accessing an element is very simple:

```
echo $a[5];
```